# Concerning the existence of the $R-$smallest element of a subset of a partially ordered set $A$

Tags: proof-verification, induction, relations, order-theory

Is the following Proof Correct?

**Theorem.** Given that $R$ is a *total-order* on $A$, every finite, non-empty set $B\subseteq A$ has an $R-$smallest element.

*Proof.* We construct the proof by recourse to *Mathematical-Induction*.

*Basis-Step:* Let $B$ be any *non-empty* subset of $A$ such that $|B|=1$ evidently the one element in $B$ is its $R-$smallest element since $R$ is *reflexive*.

*Inductive-Step:* Given any arbitrary $k\in\mathbf{Z^+}$ assume that the following is true
$$\forall X\subseteq A(|X|=k\implies\exists a\in X\forall x\in X(aRx))\tag{1}$$
Now let $Y$ be an arbitrary \textit{non-empty} subset of $A$ such that $|Y|=k+1$. We could express $Y$ as $Y=X\cup\{\beta\}$ where $X=Y\backslash\{\beta\}$ and $\beta$ is an arbitrary element of $Y$, evidently $|X|=k$ and thus from $(1)$ it follows that $X$ has an $R-$smallest element.

Let this element by $\alpha$, moreover since $R$ is a *total-order* it follows that 
$$\forall x\in A\forall y\in A(xRy\lor yRx)\tag{2}$$
thus in particular we have $\alpha R\beta\lor\beta R\alpha$ arguing from cases.

*Case-1($\alpha R\beta$):* We know that $\forall x\in X(\alpha Rx)$ this together with $\alpha R\beta$ implies that $\forall x\in Y(\alpha Rx)$ consequently $\alpha$ is the $R-$smallest element of $Y$.

*Case-2($\beta R\alpha$):* Let $x\in X$ we know that $\alpha Rx$ this together with $\beta R\alpha$ and the *transitivity* of $R$ implies that $\beta Rx$ and the *reflexivity* of $R$ implies that $\beta R\beta$ consequently $\beta$ is the $R-$smallest element of $Y$.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Looks perfectly good to me!